# How to send multiple objects from node backend to .hbs

Tags: node.js

I'm currently trying to send 2 objects to the front .hbs front end. However I cant seem to work out how to do this because I'm using promises.

Currently, my thinking is i perform the sql query, the country and organisation name is extracted, and then each sent to a geocoding api, returned and then squashed together in the same promises. But i'm not sure how to extract these for the render function.

Node

```
   //route for homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  let sql = "SELECT org_name, country_name from places;

  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {

    if (err) throw err;


    const geoPromise = param => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      geo.geocode('mapbox.places', param, function(err, geoData) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        if (geoData) {
          resolve(geoData.features[0])
        } else {
          reject('No result found');
        }
      });
    });

    const promises = results.map(result =>
      Promise.all([
        geoPromise(result.country_name),
        geoPromise(result.org_name)

      ]));



      Promise.all(promises).then((geoLoc, geoBus) => {
        res.render('layouts/layout', {
          results: JSON.stringify(geoLoc),
          businesses: JSON.stringify(geoBus)
        });
      });



  });
});
```

Front end call

```
 results1 = {{{results}}}
console.log(results1.length)

business1 = {{{businesses}}}
console.log(business1.length)
```

Comment: just after `Promise.all(promises).then((geoLoc, geoBus) => {` do a `console.log(geoLoc)`. Tell me what do you see?

Comment: geoLoc show's everything i need, geoBus is undefined.

Comment: try with `Promise.all(promises).then(([geoLoc, geoBus]) => {}`. Deconstruct the argument into an array

Comment: Deconstructing the array wasn't enough, updated my answer after thorough testing on my side with what I believe is a final, working answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Wrap your `geo.geocode` into a `Promise`

```
const geoPromise = param => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  geo.geocode('mapbox.places', param, function(err, geoData) {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    if (geoData) {
      resolve(geoData.features[0])
    } else {
      reject('No result found');
    }
  });
});
```

## Combine both calls to `geo.geocode`

```
const promises = results.map(result =>
  Promise.all([
    geoPromise(result.country_name),
    geoPromise(result.org_name)
  ]));
```

## Call them

```
Promise.all(promises).then(([geoLoc, geoBus]) => {
  res.render('layouts/layout', {
    results: JSON.stringify(geoLoc),
    businesses: JSON.stringify(geoBus)
  });
});
```

[As MadWard's answer mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853667/how-to-send-multiple-objects-from-node-backend-to-hbs/54854008#54854008), deconstructing the argument of the callback of `Promise.all` is necessary since everything will be in the first argument. Make sure you check out his post for more details

Comment: Thanks for the reply that makes sense. However businesses is still coming up as undefined on the front end, I've updated my OP to show what i'm doing now thanks to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Something important to recall: you will never have more than one argument in a `then()` callback.

Now you may ask: in the case of `Promise.all()`, what is this value?
Well, it is an array with all the values from the promises it awaits, in the order in which they are called.

If you do:

```
Promise.all([
    resolveVariable1, resolveVariable2, resolveVariable3
]).then((values) => {

})
```

`values` will be `[variable1, variable2, variable3]`, the three variables that the promises resolve to.

Your case is, however, a bit more complicated. What is gonna be returned at the end is a 2-D array containing every entry. It is an array of length `results.length`, and each of its element has a length of **2**. The first element is the `result`, and the second one is the `business`.

Here is your snippet:

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((values) => {
    let results = values.map(elmt => elmt[0]);
    let businesses = values.map(elmt => elmt[1]);
    res.render('layouts/layout', {
      results: JSON.stringify(results),
      businesses: JSON.stringify(businesses)
    });
})
```